# Glob path to get newest file only

Tags: unix, glob

Let's say I have a directory with product inventories that are saved per day:

```
$ ls *.csv
2014_01_01.csv
2014_01_02.csv
...
```

Is there a glob pattern that will only grab the newest file? Or do I need to chain it with other commands? Basically I'm just looking to do what would about to a `LIMIT 1` based on the filename sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your shell is `bash`, `ksh93` or `zsh`, and your files have the same naming convention as the example in your question:

```sh
files=( *.csv )
printf "The newest file is %s\n" "${files[-1]}"
```

Since the date in the filenames is in a format that naturally sorts, storing all of them in an array and taking the last element gives you the newest one (And conversely the first element is the oldest one).